# form validation for different condition in code igniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

So i have a form that used for two functions/conditions : Save(add) and Update
Now i set a rule to my input text : `$this->form_validation->set_rules('ID_user', 'User ID', 'required');`

The logic is like this: if the user is in Save condition then my input text will be enable because they will tyoe their id, but if the user is in Update condition then my input text will be disable and the text will be the current user id because they cant change their user id.

This is the Save(add) and update functions in my controller :

```
function add(){
    //set common properties 
    $data['title'] = 'Tambah User baru';
    $data['action'] = site_url('user/add');
    $data['link_back'] = anchor('user/index/', 'Back to User list', array('class'=>'back'));

    $this->_set_rules();
    //run validation
    if($this->form_validation->run() == false){
        $data['message'] = '';
        //bedakan add/update
        $data['validate'] = 'add';
        //set common properties 
        $data['title'] = 'Add new User';
        //$data['message'] = '';
        $data['user']['ID_user'] = '';
        $data['user']['pass'] = '';
        $data['user']['nama'] = '';
        $data['user']['email'] = '';
        $data['user']['active'] = '';
        $data['link_back'] = anchor('user/index/', 'Lihat daftar User', array('class'=>'back'));

        $this->load->view('user_form_v', $data);
    }

    else{
        //save data
        $user = array('ID_user'=>$this->input->post('ID_user'),
        'pass'=>sha1($this->input->post('pass')),
        'nama'=>$this->input->post('nama'),
        'email'=>$this->input->post('email'),
        'active'=>$this->input->post('active'),
        'regis_date'=>date('Y-m-d H:i:s'));

        $ID_user = $this->user_m->save($user);

        //set form input nama = "id"
        $this->validation->ID_user = $ID_user;

        redirect('user/index/add_success');
    }
}

function update($ID_user){
    //set common properties
    $data['title'] = 'Update user';
    $this->load->library('form_validation');

    //set validation properties
    $this->_set_rules();
    $data['action'] = ('user/update/'.$ID_user);

    //bedakan add/update
    $data['validate'] = 'update';

    //run validation
    if ($this->form_validation->run() == false){
        $data['message'] = '';

        $data['user'] = $this->user_m->get_by_id($ID_user)->row_array();
        //set common properties
        $data['title'] = 'Update User';
        $data['message'] = '';
    }
    else{
        //save data
        $ID_user = $this->input->post('ID_user');
        $user = array(
        'pass'=>$this->input->post('pass'),
        'nama'=>$this->input->post('nama'),
        'email'=>$this->input->post('email'),
        'active'=>$this->input->post('active'),
        'regis_date'=>date('Y-m-d H:i:s'));

        $this->user_m->update($ID_user, $user);
        $data['user'] = $this->user_m->get_by_id($ID_user)->row_array();

        //set user message
        $data['message'] = 'Update User Success!';
    }

    $data['link_back'] = anchor('user/index/', 'Lihat daftar user', array('class'=>'back'));
    //load view
    $this->load->view('user_form_v', $data);
}
```

And this is the input type in view :

```
<input type="text" name="ID_user" class="text"
                <?php if($validate!='add'){echo "disabled";} ?>
                value="<?php echo (isset($user['ID_user']))?$user['ID_user']:""?>"/>
```

The question is : **while my user in the Update condition and they want to Update, the error message is shown because php think that the userid is null, the fact is the user id is already there, all i do is just print the userid in my input type and disabled it**
This is the error message : `The User ID field is required.`

Comment: OUT of topic when comparing boolean like TRUE or FALSE you must use the '===' ex, if($true === TRUE)

Comment: @tomexsans i dont think so, things ran smoothly with "=="
Thanks :D

Comment: yes it rans smoothly but for good practice use === when comparing boolean read this http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/styleguide.html#comparing_return_values_and_typecasting

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could include the User ID field as a hidden field in the update form to be sure that it gets submitted with the rest of the form fields.

```
<input type="hidden" name="user[ID_user]" value="<?=$user['ID_user']?>" />
```

Just make sure to validate it somehow against the current logged in user to ensure nobody monkeys with it and changes another user's record.

Comment: I'd be wary if you're going with this solution. See TheShiftExchange's answer for the reason why.

Comment: I agree with TheShiftExchange... Which is why I said in the last sentence of my answer to make sure to validate it against whoever is logged in (should be saved in session or cookie).  Its just like any other input field in the form, always validate before writing to the db.

Answer (score 2):

You should run two different rules - once for 'saving' and one for 'updating'.

Then in the saving rule, include the rule for the user id.

In the update rule, dont include the user id.

Putting the user id into a 'hidden' field on your form is not optimal - because someone can 'edit' the page and change the hidden field to something else - thus opening up your application to be manipulated