# form validation error with hidden type code igniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, validation

This is a continue question from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12329534/form-validation-for-different-condition-in-code-igniter#comment16549157_12329534)

The case is : after i add a hidden field, now i could Update but i CANT save because everytime i try to save, this error message keep showing up : `The User ID field is required.`

This is the controller, function add is for Save and update for Update :

```
function add(){
    //set common properties 
    $data['title'] = 'Tambah User baru';
    $data['action'] = site_url('user/add');
    $data['link_back'] = anchor('user/index/', 'Back to User list', array('class'=>'back'));

    //bedakan add/update
    $data['validate'] = 'add';

    $this->_set_rules();
    //run validation
    if($this->form_validation->run() == false){
        $data['message'] = '';

        $data['title'] = 'Add new User';
        //$data['message'] = '';
        $data['user']['ID_user'] = '';
        $data['user']['pass'] = '';
        $data['user']['nama'] = '';
        $data['user']['email'] = '';
        $data['user']['active'] = '';
        $data['link_back'] = anchor('user/index/', 'Lihat daftar User', array('class'=>'back'));

        $this->load->view('user_form_v', $data);
    }

    else{
        //save data
        $user = array('ID_user'=>$this->input->post('ID_user'),
        'pass'=>sha1($this->input->post('pass')),
        'nama'=>$this->input->post('nama'),
        'email'=>$this->input->post('email'),
        'active'=>$this->input->post('active'),
        'regis_date'=>date('Y-m-d H:i:s'));

        $ID_user = $this->user_m->save($user);

        //set form input nama = "id"
        $this->validation->ID_user = $ID_user;

        redirect('user/index/add_success');
    }
}

function update($ID_user){
    //set common properties
    $data['title'] = 'Update user';
    $this->load->library('form_validation');

    //set validation properties
    $this->_set_rules();
    $data['action'] = ('user/update/'.$ID_user);

    //bedakan add/update
    $data['validate'] = 'update';

    //run validation
    if ($this->form_validation->run() == false){
        $data['message'] = '';

        $data['user'] = $this->user_m->get_by_id($ID_user)->row_array();
        //set common properties
        $data['title'] = 'Update User';
        $data['message'] = '';
    }
    else{
        //save data
        $ID_user = $this->input->post('ID_user');
        $user = array(
        'pass'=>$this->input->post('pass'),
        'nama'=>$this->input->post('nama'),
        'email'=>$this->input->post('email'),
        'active'=>$this->input->post('active'),
        'regis_date'=>date('Y-m-d H:i:s'));

        $this->user_m->update($ID_user, $user);
        $data['user'] = $this->user_m->get_by_id($ID_user)->row_array();

        //set user message
        $data['message'] = 'Update User Success!';
    }

    $data['link_back'] = anchor('user/index/', 'Lihat daftar user', array('class'=>'back'));
    //load view
    $this->load->view('user_form_v', $data);
}
```

And this is my view :

```
<input type="text" name="ID_user" class="text"
                <?php if($validate!='add'){echo "disabled";} ?>
                value="<?php echo (isset($user['ID_user']))?$user['ID_user']:""?>"/>
                <input type="hidden" name="ID_user" value="<?php echo (isset($user['ID_user']))?$user['ID_user']:""?>"/>
```

**note : if the name for input text and input hidden is SAME then the update is working but the save is not working, but if the name is different then the update is not working but the save is working @_@**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just put the hidden input element above the disabled element.

```
<input type="hidden" name="ID_user" value="<?php echo (isset($user['ID_user']))?$user['ID_user']:""?>"/>
<input type="text" name="ID_user" class="text"
                <?php if($validate!='add'){echo "disabled";} ?>
                value="<?php echo (isset($user['ID_user']))?$user['ID_user']:""?>"/>
```

The issue appears because the value is overwritten by the hidden input element (which is empty in your "save" page). By moving placing the hidden one before the may or may not be disabled one, both of the "save" and "update" page will work correctly. In the update page, it'll work because if the input is disabled, it will not get sent to the server (i.e. it will not overwrite the hidden one).

However, in my opinion, using a hidden input is not very secure. Users can easily change the value by editing the HTML using tools like Firebug or Chrome developer tools. You might want to look into session as a solution instead.

Comment: Thank you very much, you saved my day Sir :D
Btw, can you explain where i insert a variable to my hidden element?i dont really understand this code, especially the hidden input one

Comment: @BlazeTama what do you mean? You're already outputting the necessary variable for the hidden input in your code.

Comment: Okay, i slowly get it now..Thanks :D

Answer (score 1):

you shold give different names for input text,input hidden.You given both "ID_user".Try like this

```
 <input type="text" name="ID_user" class="text"
            <?php if($validate!='add'){echo "disabled";} ?>
            value="<?php echo (isset($user['ID_user']))?$user['ID_user']:""?>"/>
            <input type="hidden" name="ID_user_hidden" value="<?php echo            (isset($user['ID_user']))?$user['ID_user']:""?>"/>
```

Comment: Thanks,but after i change the hidden name, the update is not working again(the error comes up) but the save is working @_@
What should i do?

Comment: @BlazeTama if you really just wanting a quick fix solution, just move the hidden element up, before the disabled one.

Comment: Oh in the update page u r getting error..???then post the values from db on which the id contains into ur view file